# Send OSC messages from react native

Tags: react-native, osc, opensoundcontrol

Im trying to send OSC messages (open sound control) from a vue-native (vue wrapper for react-native) app straight to an application called Touchdesigner.

I have now solved this by sending messages from my client app on my android to a node server where I am forwarding the message as OSC which I am receiving in Touchdesigner.

I wounder if there are a better way of doing this? Basically I want to send messages straight to Touchdesigner application which allows me to receive OSC messages. But I cannot find a way of sending osc-messages from vue-native.

Is there a vue-native / react native way of sending osc messages?

Answer (score 1):

I created [react-native-osc](https://github.com/luiscript/react-native-osc) that allows you to send OSC messages from React Native:

```
npm install react-native-osc
cd ios && pod install
```

Usage:

```js
import osc from 'react-native-osc';
osc.createClient("localhost", 9090);
osc.sendMessage("/address/", [1.0, 0.0]);
```

I hope it hepls.